# Very simple vim syntax file

Tags: vim, syntax, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to create a very simple vim syntax file that only highlights specific keywords

I saved a file called `coffee.vim` in `~/.vim/syntax/`

the file has `syn keyword basicLanguageKeywords if then for in of do` in it

Am I on the right track?

Where do I go from here to actually use that simple vim syntax file?

Comment: If you want these commands to be applied on top of another syntax plugin you want to leave as is, it would be better to put it in `~/.vim/after/syntax`

Answer (score 5):

You're nearly there. You need to specify the colouring of the basicLanguageKeywords type with a line such as:

```
 hi def link basicLanguageKeywords   Conditional
```

(this tells the current colourscheme what to do with the keywords). Then, you can tell Vim to use this syntax by setting the filetype:

```
 setlocal filetype=coffee
```

That should be all that's needed. If you want all files ending in .coffee to use this syntax file you can add something like

```
 autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.coffee setlocal filetype=coffee
```

to your .vimrc.

Hope this helps.